# In LyX, is there a way to toggle the display of TeX code in math expressions?

Tags: math-mode, lyx, editors

Is there a way to toggle the display of math expressions in LyX between the default, which makes an attempt at replacing TeX code with easy to read symbols (but is short of actual rendering), and the underlying TeX code?

For example, I'd like the be able to toggle between this

[image: Default mode for displaying math in LyX]

and this

[image: Desired TeX mode for displaying math in LyX]

Comment: Given the view count, the developers should really consider adding a button for this action.

Comment: @TomášZato or even just a command/menu item...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not a built-in toggle that I know of. But you can create one yourself by using a command sequence. First place your cursor in front of the math expression that you want to convert to LaTeX. Press alt+x to go to the command buffer (or go to view>toolbars>command buffer and then click on it at the bottom). Enter the following command and press return:

```
command-sequence char-forward; line-end-select ; cut; char-backward; paste; char-delete-forward`
```

This works for me. Does it work for you? If it works, make a shortcut for it. And then when you want to go back, just select the LaTeX code and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>.

Here are some additional suggestions:

- go to View > Code Preview Pane to get a look at the LaTeX code around where your cursor is.
- if you put your cursor inside the math box, copy (but don't copy the entire math box), go outside of math, and paste, it will paste the LaTeX code. To turn that LaTeX code back into the math symbols, highlight it, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>.

Comment: One could bind a keyboard shortcut to View source as well, which could make it more convenient to use. The action is `dialog-toggle view-source`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. good suggestion.

Comment: `View -> Source` is now `View -> Code Preview Pane`.

Comment: @flow2k thanks, just updated it.

Answer (score 2):

No. The closest you can get (as of version 2.0.3) is to view the source (`View > View Source`) with the selection near an equation of interest, or to copy the contents of the expression (not the whole math box) and paste it somewhere.

Comment: @scottkosty: This is closer to what I'm looking for (the question is not about "Instant Preview"). If the question could be rewritten like this, I'd accept it.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want me to edit my answer and take out the instant preview suggestion? I'm not worried about having my answer accepted but I would be happy to improve the clarity.

Comment: @scottkosty: That would be great. Just refocus to answer the question itself first, then the additional suggestions if you like.

Comment: I made some edits. See if you like the new "solution"